# Kendo ui chart hide circle for data points

Tags: charts, telerik, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I'm not able to hide rounded circle for the line chart in Kendo ui. I do want to show tooltip value but want to hide circle.

below example is from demo site: http://demos.kendoui.com/dataviz/line-charts/index.html
[image]

Even, I don't know what do they call it so that I can find in the document here: http://docs.kendoui.com/api/dataviz/chart

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet. Let me know if any concern.

```
<style>
    #chart circle {
        display: none !important;
    }
</style>
<script>
    function createChart() {
        $("#chart").kendoChart({
            title: {
                text: "Gross domestic product growth /GDP annual %/"
            },
            legend: {
                position: "bottom"
            },
            chartArea: {
                background: ""
            },
            seriesDefaults: {
                type: "line"
            },
            series: [{
                name: "India",
                data: [3.907, 7.943, 7.848, 9.284, 9.263, 9.801, 3.890, 8.238, 9.552, 6.855]
            }, {
                name: "World",
                data: [1.988, 2.733, 3.994, 3.464, 4.001, 3.939, 1.333, -2.245, 4.339, 2.727]
            }, {
                name: "Russian Federation",
                data: [4.743, 7.295, 7.175, 6.376, 8.153, 8.535, 5.247, -7.832, 4.3, 4.3]
            }, {
                name: "Haiti",
                data: [-0.253, 0.362, -3.519, 1.799, 2.252, 3.343, 0.843, 2.877, -5.416, 5.590]
            }],
            valueAxis: {
                labels: {
                    format: "{0}%"
                },
                line: {
                    visible: false
                },
                axisCrossingValue: -10
            },
            categoryAxis: {
                categories: [2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011],
                majorGridLines: {
                    visible: false
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                visible: false
            }
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(createChart);
</script>
```

Comment: so, this was the trick: #chart circle {
        display: none !important;
    }

Thanks.

Comment: and if I'd like to reduce the radius/size? I've seen they are rendered as <circle> tags with an attribute "r=4", but I haven't found a way to reduce it. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 17):

According to the docs, you can set series.markers.visible to false:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-series.markers.visible

Additionally you can change their size and shape.